# Google Sheets - Split Data

Tags: google-sheets

I have these data in Google Sheets

```
$71,675_x000d_
$80,356_x000d_
$107,361_x000d_
$123,393_x000d_
$116,878
```

I want them to be split into different columns.

However, when I do so using Data > Split Data into Different Columns, it separates $71 and 675_x000d_ but I need the $71,275 and remove the *xoood*

Please note that the last number doesn't have those extra characters.

Please help.

Comment: What if you use "\_" (underscore) as a custom separator? Does that help? Depends whether you need \_x000d\_ to appear in the next column or just want to remove it.

Comment: Keyur, please update your question to include the new information you added as a comment to @Erik's answer.  You could also paste in the image you provided into your question, rather than providing it as a link.  But sharing a sample sheet always helps, and makes it easier (less work!) for anyone trying to work on your problem.  See this guide: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post says you want to "remove the *x000d* (that is, extract only the dollar amounts). That said, let's say your raw data starts in A2 (i.e., the data is in A2:A). Place the following formula into the first cell of another otherwise empty column (e.g., B1):

`=ArrayFormula({"Extracted";IF(A2:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A&"_",",",""),"\d+"))})`

**How It Works:**

ArrayFormula(...) signifies that we'll be processing an entire range and not just one cell.

The outer curly brackets {...} signify that a virtual array will be formed from non-like or non-contiguous pieces.

The first piece of the virtual array is the header. Here, that is "Extracted"; but you can change it as you like.

The semicolon means "place the next information below the previous part."

`IF(A2:A="",, ...)` is a standard check that basically says "Don't try to process any blank cells in Column A"; or alternatively worded, "If any cell in A2:A is blank/null, do nothing."

Skipping the REGEXEXTRACT for now, `A2:A&"_"` appends an underscore to every entry in A2:A. This allows entries in A2:A that are just a dollar amount (e.g., from the post, `$116,878`) to have a consistent symbol following them if not already there. (And adding the underscore to anything that already *has* an underscore won't matter, because we won't be extracting that far out.)

Now that we've got the new strings, we SUBSTITUTE every comma for a null (i.e., delete all commas).

Finally, REGEXEXTRACT will take all of the virtually modified strings and extract `\d+`, which means only digits (`\d`) in an unbroken sequence of any length greater than 0 (`+`). Note that REGEXEXTRACT will only return the *first* such match it encounters as written, so `000` will not be extracted.

An IFERROR wrap is placed around the REGEXEXTRACT, just in case you have any situations in real life that don't have any sequence of numbers at all. In these cases, nothing will be returned (whereas, without the IFERROR, an error would have been returned).

Once the extraction is done, you can apply **Format > Number > Currency (rounded)** to the entire column.

**Addendum:**

After an additional comment (below), it appears that the raw data is in Column T, that all five entries are in one cell and that the OP would like all five amounts extracted across each row. That being the case, assuming that Columns U:Y are empty to start, place the following in cell U1 (not U2):

`=ArrayFormula({"Va11","Val2","Val3","Val4","Val5";IF(T2:T="",,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(T2:T&"_",",",""),REPT("\$(\d+)[^\$]*",5))))})`

This works much the same way as the previous formula. The differences:

There are five headers now.

You'll see `REPT(...,5)` here. This is an easy way to repeat the same extraction five times.

That repeated extraction is now the following:

`\$(\d+)[^\$]*`

The backslash in front of the dollar signs means to treat those symbols as literals instead of as their usual meaning (i.e., end-of-string). So the extraction reads as follows:

`\$` anything that starts with a dollar sign
`(\d+) extract what is between the ( ), which is any group of digits` [^$]*` followed by any number (including 0) characters that are not dollar signs

As I said, the REPT will repeat this five times; so five groups matching this pattern will be extracted.

Understand that if you have *any* groups that don't follow the pattern exactly, resulting in five matching extractions, *nothing* will be returned.

*Be sure* to format U:Y as currency rounded, or you will wind up with some of those numbers translating as *raw dates* and therefore being completely off.

Comment: Well that works but I have in total 5 values in one column. Check this image link - https://ibb.co/kDJQYGT - Also, is it possible to put those 5 into same rows but different columns.

Comment: First of all, you've placed the formula into U2 instead of U1. It needs to go in U1 as explained in my answer above, or everything will be off by one row. That said, I will edit my original answer with another formula that will handle 5 (and exactly 5) entries in one cell.

Comment: Thank you @Erik - That works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following formula and format cells to your needs.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"\n|_x000d_","√"),"√")))
```

The big advantage of the above formula compared to others is that it **works for any number of lines included within a single cell** (as shown in the image below).

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: The big advantage of this formula compared to others is that it **works for any number of lines included within a single cell** (as shown in the image).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SPLIT` function:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A:A),SPLIT(A:A,"_x000d_",FALSE),""))
```

[image]